How to Maintain Consistent Merge Strategies Across Long-Living Branches?
In our Azure DevOps project, we have three long living branches that are all protected to prevent devs to push directly to these branches:

develop
staging
main

Basically one feature is developed in branch abc, merge to develop after a pull request review with squash. From time to time we merge no squash this time from develop to staging and test on our pre production environment.
After we are satifyied, we create a release branch, generate the changelogs and push the changes to main, also no squash.
Our feature abc is now on main but now we want to get the changelogs back to develop. We need to merge from master to staging no squash, then down from staging to develop no squash.
Actually it works very well. The only thing we struggle with is that, in the merge phase we complete the PR on develop with squash and in the merge back phase without squash. It's very error prone.
How could we solve that?

Short answer: don't use long-lived branches :-)

I think we need more info what what you mean with "error prone". Also, I humbly think you could consider merging master into develop directly, instead of using staging as a middle layer to get the changes from master into develop.

Don't use squash merge, and you have only one strategy to deal with.  Squash merges cannot work between long-lived branches, so to choose a single strategy, it has to be merge commits.

Thanks for your answers. @RuiJarimba long-lived branches are working well. It's also easier to know which code is on the environments because we need prod=main, stage=staging, dev=develop @eftshift0 This does not change our issue with develop. Actually we would like to bypass the build validations and review process (maybe inside a pipeline) when merging back.

Squash merges are an utterly stupid idea that absolutely nobody should use. It destroys most of the benefits git has over other version control systems.

@hlovdal Keep cool, we just squash the commit of a feature or bug fixing together. Which benefits over other version control systems, squash destroys?

To summarize, you only used Squash merge on the develop branch in one case: one feature is developed in branch feature-abc, merge to develop after a pull request review with squash. In other cases, Squash merge was not used.
In this case, it may be possible to create an automatically running pipeline to determine whether the current pull request to develop branch uses Squash merge and change the Limit merge types policy based the result.
Here's how it theoretically works:

First, we need a pipeline which will be triggered when a pull request is created. We can refer the steps here Generic webhook based triggers for YAML pipelines. We need to create an Incoming WebHook service connection and the webhook with the event A pull request is created in a Git repository.

In the pipeline, we can get the source branch Name through ${{ parameters.MyWebhookTrigger.resource.sourceRefName}}. When the source branch Name is feature-abc (or contains key word feature), use the Rest API Merge strategy policy to change the policy with the "useSquashMerge": true.

Note that you should avoid creating multiple pull requests for the develop branch at the same time.


The above approach may increase the complexity of the process. If you want it to be less complicated, maybe you need to use some training sessions to let your team members know which merge type to use under what circumstances.

Thanks for your complete answer :) Yeah like you said it adds too much complexity...

Yes, this adds complexity. But once the entire process is set up, it runs automatically, avoiding accidental mistakes. Anyway, it depends on your preference.  Happy coding! :)
